# have a list of ggplots in R, would like to put them in a folder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a list of graphs using this function:

```
p.list = lapply(sort(unique(new$tree)), function(i){ 
  ggplot(new[new$tree==i,], aes(age,height)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() + facet_wrap(~tree)})
```

This produced a list of 34 graphs, but I cannot view them. I am hoping to save them as separate files (save them as .jpeg images) in a single folder, and have each file labelled by "tree". Any advice on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi rachel. Do you mean save them as images? pdfs? R objects? svg files?

Comment: I would like to save them as images! My apologies for not clarifying

Comment: Any special graphics format? png, jpeg, tiff, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple loop:

```r
for(i in seq_along(p.list)){
  jpeg(filename = paste0("ggplot_", sort(unique(new$tree))[i], ".jpg"))
  print(p.list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

This will write the files `ggplot_1.jpg`, `ggplot_2.jpg` etc to your home directory.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to name them according to the "tree" value?

Comment: @rrachel95 I can't test it because I don't have access to your data structure, but I think my update should do what you need

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `ggsave`. It allows to specify the device as an argument.

```
tree_names <- sort(unique(iris$Species))
folder_name <- "~/tmp"
for(i in seq_along(p.list)){
  flname <- paste0("tree_", tree_names[i], ".jpeg")
  flname <- file.path(folder_name, flname)
  ggsave(flname, plot = p.list[[i]], device = "jpeg")
}
#Saving 4.68 x 5.84 in image
#Saving 4.68 x 5.84 in image
#Saving 4.68 x 5.84 in image
```

**Data**

As a test data set I have used the following based on the built-in data set `iris`.

```
p.list <- lapply(sort(unique(iris$Species)), function(i){ 
  ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i,], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme_classic()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

A more tidyverse-y answer using the iris data as per Rui Barradas:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

p.list <- iris %>% 
  pull(Species) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  sort() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(function(i){ 
        ggplot(filter(iris, Species == i), aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
           geom_point() + 
           theme_classic()
    })

iwalk(p.list, ~ ggsave(glue("{.y}.jpg"), .x, device = "jpeg"))
```